# Charset on Linux server with Git

Tags: linux, git, utf-8

We have some trouble with special signs in our (javascript) application like €.

The files looks correct when we open they on our development pc's but when pulled on our production server the sign is showing up like `â‚¬`. In the browser but also in the file itselfs.

I guess it is something with the charset or locale setting on the server, but when executing `locale` I see that it's set to UTF-8 already.

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8
```

What can be the issue here?

Comment: What charset is your HTTP server using? Check the `Content-Type` header. If you look at the file with a [hex editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor) to see the actual bytes, you can figure out what character set is in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the defaultCharset of Apache. This is now set to UTF-8

```
/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/charset.conf 
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```